# Creating a Windows 7 All-in-One CD with Service Pack 1

Tags: windows-7, service-pack, slipstream

At our computer shop, we followed the instructions for creating a Windows 7 disk for any edition (SOURCE: http://www.anandtech.com/show/3564), one disk for 32 bit and one disk for 64 bit. I am not finding any information on creating such a disk with Service Pack 1 slipstreamed into it. I looked here on Superuser, and found links for RT 7 to put it in, but it creates one disk per edition, per architecture. Is there a way to have it slipstreamed, and still have the Windows 7 installation ask what edition of Windows to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option to *find* Windows 7 with SP1 ISOs, remove ei.cfg and then burn the DVDs...

here's a link [FINAL Media Refresh MSDN Windows 7 Ultimate SP1_U x86/x64 ISO at MyDigitalLife](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/27069-FINAL-Media-Refresh-MSDN-Windows-7-Ultimate-SP1_U-x86-x64-ISO-Download-English?s=3266c28242402aaff989b8fa88ff303e) to find ISOs and you can also verify SHA1 at Microsoft's Technet downloads: [Technet Downloads](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx)

Comment: +1.  This is legal *if and only if* you have a legitimate serial number.  You pay for the license, not the installation media.

Comment: +cp2141 or if you only try the trial

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the `ei.cfg` file in the `sources` directory of the ISO/disc, it will prompt you to select which edition to install.  The `ei.cfg` file specifies [various things](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-choose-desired-windows-7-edition-version-during-setup/) about the edition to install (e.g. volume licensing, OEM/retail distributions).

If this file is present on the disc, the installer assumes that is the edition to install.  Without this file, the installer has no choice but to prompt the end-user to select the proper edition.

Comment: That's what we did for SP0, but with SP1, we get a BSOD once setup starts

Comment: Probably should make sure the disk actually **has** everything in the first place.  I personally use Windows AIK, from the horse's mouth.

Comment: @Luke is this an MSDN SP1 ISO, or an SP0 updated to SP1?

Comment: Originally, it was an OEM copy that we took out the ei.cfg file to make it generic. We tried to slipstream SP1 into that, and it failed

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to install windows, install the updates / programs you want universally -> and then just do a backup using the disk image utility built into windows 7.

Load a windows 7 boot disk into the computer needing the new o/s - and plug in an external HD with the backup. I think you have to click recover, from the repair screen - and locate the backup image on the external.

Being that you're a computer shop, I imagine you have several external HDs. I imagine this might fit on a dual-layer DVD / blu-ray / large USB if you have those as well.

Comment: there are definitely compatibility issues, but it has worked 5/5 times i've done it this way. Slipstreaming is a pain in the arse...

Comment: That’s not an ideal method because it leaves a lot of extraneous files and registry entires behind that would not be present in a fresh SP1 installation.